# Right to left in equation box words in reverse in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, right-to-left

I am trying to type inside of the equation box in Word in Hebrew (which is right to left language) but the order of the words is reversed.

So if I write the first word the then the best word I want to write will come to the right of the first word instead of to the left as it must.

I tried setting the keyboard in Windows correctly which I guess I have done correctly (only have English with English keyboard and Hebrew with Hebrew keyboard.

I also deleted from office cache plus even the data and options registry in regedit.

Anyone can help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

Press the "Use non-math text in a math region" button. This works well for Hebrew only text, mixing Hebrew and English/math doesn't work well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MS Office applications, including Word, supports [right-to-left text entry on a per/paragraph basis.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-to-left-language-features-17d8a34d-36d6-49ad-b765-257cb7cd22e2)

- Enable **both R->L and L->R languages** to view the *Left-to-right* and *Right-to-left paragraph buttons*. To do this, set English as the display language in *Office*, and עִברִית as the display language in *Windows*, or *vice versa*.
- Both the *Left-to-right* and *Right-to-left* paragraph buttons should now be visible in MS Word.

[image: MS Word Language direction buttons]

That said, the most convenient way to insert a Hebrew word *within* a block of Latin (or Roman, if you prefer) text is to copy the Hebrew from a R->L paragraph and paste it into the other paragraph (as I've done above). Somehow, the document pastes the letters in the correct order, but if you move the caret near the word, directional control behaves oddly.

See also [this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/562109/how-do-i-set-the-the-text-direction-in-word-2010-to-right-to-left-for-languages).

Comment: Actually I tried it myself right after writing this question haha 
Thank you for the answer!!!