# changing the Heading Styles from Right to Left to Left to Right

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010

I am writing a document through Microsoft office 2010 in English. I copied and pasted another document. since then, my Heading styles have changed and they are from Right to left. the same has happened to my table of content style.
I would appreciate to tell me how to make them from Left to Right again.

Answer (score 0):

If your worksheet looks like:

[image]

Clear the right to left checkbox in Options:

[image]

To restore the normal sheet display.

Answer (score 0):

There are [*Right-to-Left* (R>L) and *Left-to-Right* (L>R) buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/562109/how-do-i-set-the-the-text-direction-in-word-2010-to-right-to-left-for-languages) available when there are multiple languages installed.

- If you do not have both L>R and R>L languages installed, [install one for the text direction needed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-language-or-set-language-preferences-in-office-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d).
- A button to change text direction should be in the ribbon.
  [image: L>R Text Direction Button]
- You can also use the [keyboard shortcuts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_global_experience/2010/02/19/useful-tricks-and-shortcuts-for-users-around-the-world/) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to set text direction.